# RabbitMQ, and web services

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, node.js, rabbitmq

I've been tasked with taking a RabbitMQ queue, processing the messages (key and values) to filter out unneeded items (based on the key), and delaying the results before making them available via a webservice.

Being new to RabbitMQ, it seems like my best approach was to write a windows client that retrieves messages from the queue, filters it accordingly and puts it into a custom class collection (System.Collection.Queue).  Whenever an item in this collection has been stored for X seconds, the message data would be pushed into public collection to overwrite the existing value based on the key.

This publicly accessible collection would be exposed as a REST service returning json data.

This would loop indefinitely for as long as the client was running.

The end client is a javascript widget that will connect to this webservice, and probably poll it every second.   It seems like my approach would work, but I am concerned the process would be too intensive? I get the feeling there might be a better solution.

I was originally thinking node.js might be a good fit for this project, but I'm predominantly an asp.net developer, so I'm happy to consider other solutions, perhaps like SignalR, Web API, WCF?

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you're worried about is polling, no RabbitMQ.  A push solution is a better fit, if you can dictate technology that supports it.  Since SignalR and other websocket solutions allow push notifications, it's a great fit for this.

I don't think personally you need a windows application - you can do worker tasks in ASP easily.  The .NET parallels library now has great support for producer / consumer patterns using blocking collections as well.

So you could just do
-message recieved - add to blocking queue

-blocking queue consumer gets message and

-starts new task for message

-sleep task for amount of time wanted

-add to web APIs output queue

-push new messages out through websocket